# Remove updateLog on Solr server

Tags: solr

I've noticed that there is 25% improvement in indexing rate when I disable the updateLog (by removing it from solrconfig.xml).
The server is standalone and we are not using atomic update.
I was wondering if there are other side effects or features which will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 4.0 is it used for atomic document updates and realtime gets. If you don't use those features you can disable it.

**Atomic document updates** lets you update a field without sending the entire document. For example you could have a document view counter which you want to increment each time a document is viewed:

[ {"id":"doc1234543", "viewcount":{"inc":1} } ]

and this is much more efficient.

**Realtime gets** let you view a document immediately after it is added to an index before a commit has been executed, which is costly. This is useful if you are using Solr as a NoSQL data store.

Some more information here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig